# Group by clause usage in Postgresql

Tags: node.js, postgresql, group-by

I have a code:

```
SELECT mac, rssi, esp32cihaz FROM esp32tri where rssi<0 group by esp32cihaz ORDER BY esp32cihaz DESC LIMIT 3
```

But I have an error **`SQL state: 42803`**
My table

```
mac      rssi        esp32cihaz
ac       -61,3636      rssi1
ac        -60,8974     rssi2
ac      -63,8462       rssi3
ac      -69            rssi3
ac      -68,75         rssi3
```

my desired output

```
mac      rssi        esp32cihaz
ac       -61,3636      rssi1
ac        -60,8974     rssi2
ac      -63,8462       rssi3
```

Where is my mistake?

Thank you for your helps

Comment: group by as an aggregate operation。
you need aggregate function, such as max, sum, avg ..etc.

Comment: Can you give an example or provide a reason why this works?

Comment: Its not correct always

Comment: is this your data or output

Comment: this is my data

Comment: Post your desired output also.

Comment: ı have added my desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of `group by` clause with `select` statement, all columns which are not present in  aggregation function must appear in `group by` clause. Otherwise it will throw `SQL state: 42803` error

In your case, you should mention all 3 columns in `group by` clause like below because you are not using any aggregation function in your query:

```
SELECT mac,min(rssi),esp32cihaz FROM esp32tri where rssi<0 group by mac,esp32cihaz ORDER BY esp32cihaz
```

considering field `rssi` is numeric

[**DEMO**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6iUsSNx33YWsCMaa13UFst/1)

Comment: I want three diffrent esp32cihaz.in your code I cannot get three different rows grouping by esp32cihaz

Comment: then you should provide table schema, data and desired output in your question. Edit your question and add it. I have just given the solution of your error.

Comment: thank you.last question. This code also works for different mac?

Comment: yes it will work on different combination of `mac` and `esp32cihaz`. [See Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6iUsSNx33YWsCMaa13UFst/2).